# Return length of longest word in string (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Desired outcome is a the length of the longest word in a given string (numerical).

Ex: findLongestWord('I like tacos');   => 5

I get the 'cannot read length of undefined' error message when I start the loop from the end, and I only get the first new value of 'longest' when I start the loop forward.  What am I missing?

```
function findLongestWord(string) {
  var longest = 0;
  var array = string.split(' ');
  for (var i = array.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (array[i].length > longest) {
        longest = array[i].length;
    }
  }
  return longest;
}
```

Comment: Start with `var i  = array.length - 1`. (I can't guess what's going wrong when you run the loop forward, since you don't show specific code for that.)

Comment: Just do: `for (var i = array.length; i--;) {`

Comment: `array.reduce((res, s) => Math.max(res, s.length), 0)`

Comment: Even shorter (complete code): `Math.max(...string.split(" ").map(a => a.length));`.

Comment: `string.split(' ')` only searches for spaces, but ignores line breaks, punctuation etc. A better way to separate words would be `string.split(/[\W\b]+/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop first runs on `i` index which points to `array.length` that you're trying to access with the value of `undefined`.

> Taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length), Array length returns a 32-bit integer that is
>   always numerically gerater than the highest index of the array.

**In short, `array.length` is zero-based index.**

So modifying your code to this will do,

```
function findLongestWord(string) {
  var longest = 0;
  var array = string.split(' ');
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (array[i].length > longest) {
        longest = array[i].length;
    }
  }
  return longest;
}
```

But, here's another way you can achieve this...

```
function findLongestWord(str){
  var longestWord = '';
  str.split(' ').forEach(function (v) {
    longestWord = v.length > longestWord.length ? v : longestWord
  });
  return longestWord;
}

var word = findLongestWord('I like tacos');
console.log(longestWord, longestWord.length);
// tacos 5
```

Answer (score 1):

change your for to `for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {`

if there `4` elements in array index start from `0` to `3` hence in that case `array[4]` is `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

array.length returns ,n, the number of elements in the array and when we fetch elements from the array using index it is from 0 to n-1.
So you will have to use array.length -1 instead of array.length.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.sort` will be easy .When you sorted array in DESC order ,get longest string by just index 0.

```
function findLongestWord(string) {       
  var array = string.split(' ');
  longest = array.sort(function(a,b){
      return a.length < b.length;
  });
  return longest[0].length;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for the great suggestions!  I now see there are cleaner/shorter ways to handle this toy problem but I went with adding the 'length -1' to my loop, as that's the closest to what I had come up on my own.

Thanks!